# can spring cloud gateway be used by both front end and backend services at the same time?

Tags: frontend, microservices, backend, spring-cloud-gateway

Currently we are using [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/) as a front for our website. So when a web browser hits certain URLs, the gateway will re-route the front end to different microservices.  This is working pretty good for us.  Now we are wondering if we can additionally use the same Spring Cloud Gateway service to re-route calls from other external backend services.  So our Spring Cloud Gateway would service frontend and backend calls.  Does this sound like a good idea? Or is there a potential flaw with this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the approach you spoke of is in some scenarios valid, but many would consider an antipattern.

I, personally, would go with a lightweight Message Queue for backend-to-backend communication. However, if you decide to go with your approach, be mindful of the following issues:

- Increased latency: Your requests will have an additional step to go through, and all the overhead associated with it.
- Single Point of Failure: Gateways usually serve as an entry point for frontend or external services - which doesn't mean that if it fails, the backend dies. However, if you use it for cross-service communication, that can very likely be the case.
- Coupling: You would need to store info about routes of other services on the source service.
- Complex Configuration: If you want to avoid coupling above, you would require a way for services to register and fetch routes on the gateway - which can introduce coupling on it's own, but at least not coupling between services.
- Scalability: You would have to scale gateway appropriately. When it serves as a central point for serving public APIs to frontend - there's little to no traffic, but if you add cross-service communication - it might become a bottleneck very quickly.
- Maintenance Overhead: Your logging will always have these extra steps of going through the gateway.

To me it looks like the gateway would grow in complexity significantly, and there would be no benefits to it.